# prime and irreducible elements $\equiv 1$ modulo $4$

Tags: prime-numbers, irreducible-polynomials, unique-factorization-domains

Consider the set $L= n \in \mathbb{N}$, such that $n \equiv 1$ modulo $4$.

1) What is the set of prime or irreducible elements in $L$?

2) Is prime and irreducible the same (in $L$)?

3) Is there a unique factorization of irreducible elements $\forall n \in L$?

I know that a prime number in $\mathbb{N}$ has to be prime in $L$, too. But are there any more?

I think you can find irreducible elements which are not prime, but didn't manage to do so, yet.

Could you please help me with this problem? I'm stuck..

[Are Hilbert primes also Hilbert irreducible ? Furthermore, are Hilbert primes also primes in $\mathbb{ Z}$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1446993/are-hilbert-primes-also-hilbert-irreducible-furthermore-are-hilbert-primes-al)

Comment: Hint:  note that $21\times 209 = 57\times 77$.  Are any of those four numbers reducible?

Comment: Thanks for the comments, I'll go through it!
Now I see that $9 \mid 21*33$, but $9 \nmid 21,33$, so prime and irreducible is not the same.

Comment: @lulu: Thanks for the hint! To I can say they are not reducible by trying to multiplicate alle smaller numbers in $L$. Is there a shorter way to show this?

Comment: Sure, just factor.  $21=3\times 7, 209=13\times 19$.  As you can see, I took the first four primes (congruent to $3\pmod 4$). In retrospect, you can do it more efficiently as $9\times 49=21^2$.  Same principle of course.

Comment: Sure, sorry for not seeing it earlier. Thank you!

Comment: Could you help me with 1), too?

Comment: I shortly want to say that I really do not understand why I got -2 on my question. I indeed tried to find something before I asked, but as I didn't know the name of this set, I couldn't find anything. But I still searched and read through other questions before I asked this. So I do not understand why my question is "unclear and not useful" and "does not show any research effort". I don't want to be impolite, but to my mind, that is not justified.

Comment: Well...any thoughts?  Do you know the definition of "prime" and "irreducible"?

Comment: Note:  I certainly didn't downvote this but at a guess people were objecting to the lack of effort shown.  More to the point, it looks like a homework problem and people here are allergic to that sort of thing.  Personally, I read it differently...I think the notions of "prime" vs. "irreducible" are subtle and I'm not surprised someone would draw a blank on this sort of question.

Comment: Okay, I got that. Thank you for answering me.

Comment: So, let $l \in L$.

Case 1: $l$ is prime in $\mathbb{Z} \rightarrow$ l prime in $L \rightarrow$ $l$ irreducible in $L$.

Case 2: $l$ is not prime in $\mathbb{Z}$. Then $l$ has a unique prime factorisation in $\mathbb{Z}$. Let $l = p_1*...*p_r*q_1*...*q_s$, where $p_i \equiv 1 $ mod $4$ and $q_i \equiv 3$ mod $4$ $\forall i$.

Case 2a: There is no such $q_i$ in the factorisation $\rightarrow$ p is reducible in $L$ $\rightarrow$ p is not prime in $L$.

Case 2b: There is no such $p_i$ in the factorisation of $l$. Then if $s=2$ $\rightarrow$ $l$ is irreducible.

Comment: Moreover, if $s$ is odd, then $l \notin L$ $\rightarrow$ contradiction. If $s$ is even and $s > 2$, then $l$ is reducible $\rightarrow$ l is not prime.
And then I have the cases that $r$ and $s$ are both either even or odd. What is still left is the following:
When are such numbers irreducible, but not prime?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is one of those questions where the OEIS can really help you out; it certainly helped me write this answer. The OEIS is like Google, but for sequences of integers.

To make sure that we're on the same page: a number is irreducible if it's divisible only by units (just $1$ in this case) and associates (trivially itself in this case). But a number $p$ is prime if whenever $p \mid ab$, either $p \mid a$ or $p \mid b$. If $p \mid ab$ but $p \nmid a$ ***and*** $p \nmid b$, then $p$ is not prime.

Then the irreducible numbers in your $L$ (I prefer $\mathcal S$) are $$5, 9, 13, 17, 21, 29, 33, 37, 41, 49, 53, 57, 61, 69, 73, 77, 89, 93, 97, \ldots$$ (look this up in the OEIS for a longer listing). As you can see, this list contains some numbers that are composite in $\mathbb Z$, like $9$ and $21$.

Now notice that $9 \times 49 = 21^2 = 441$. Obviously $9 \mid 441$. However, $9 \nmid 21$, nor $21$ either (I'm writing that twice on purpose). Therefore $9$ is irreducible but not prime. This shows that factorization in $\mathcal S$ is not always unique. We can also conclude that all primes are irreducible, but not all irreducibles are prime.

P.S. One more example that factorization in $\mathcal S$ is not always unique: $693 = 9 \times 77 = 21 \times 33$. Together with $441$, that should be enough to find more numbers like that in the OEIS.

Comment: Thank you for answering me. I now managed to do the rest, i.e. $l$ is irreducible in $L$, but not prime in $L$, iff $l=l_1*l_2$, where $l_1, l_2$ prime in $\mathbb{N}$, but $l_1,l_2 \notin L$.